# How to insert a record with a column values a autoincrement pk value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table like something like below, I use this to save the upload image name. The customer want the image to be `{id}.{jpg|gif}`.

```
create table imgae(
id int autoincrement,
image text
)
```

How can i insert a new record with only one sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with a single SQL statement in MySQL. If MySQL supported Oracle-style sequences, you would be able to do this in a single statement. But because auto_increment won't give you the next id until *after* the insert has taken place, you need to actually have the row inserted before having access to the id. The closest you can get in MySQL is this:

```
insert into imgae (image) values (null);
update imgae set image=concat(last_insert_id(), '.jpg') where id=last_insert_id();
```

BTW: I see your table is called `imgae` which is probably a typo. Did you mean to call it `image`? Also, when I tried to run your `create table` statement, it failed. I had to make a couple of changes to get it to work so I could validate my answer. It should look like this:

```
create table imgae(id int auto_increment primary key, image text);
```

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. Thanks for your answer.In fact, I am using the Symfony sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable, which seems to I have to determine the image name before the insert sql run. It is difficult to have the image name with an autoincrement Pk value.

Comment: @xdazzyy: I understand it's convenient to have the pk in the filename, and it's certainly possible to do. But IMO, it's not worth the extra complexity you'll have to add to make it work. Surely this is a nice-to-have and not a hard requirement. Is it?

Comment: @xdazzyy: Is doing it in a single SQL statement also a hard requirement? Can you do it in two statements like in my example?

Comment: Thanks very much. It looks like to do it with two statements.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO "imgae" VALUES("image") (CONCAT(LAST("id") + 1, /*Script code for fetching the extension/))

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. He wants a row in the table where the `image` column has the auto-generated primary key as part of the column value (followed by `.gif` or `.jpg`). It's kind of a chicken and egg issue.

Comment: Thanks Asaph, I found that the type of image is "text" then corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO imgae (image) VALUES (CONCAT(LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1, ".jpg"));
```

But, that doesn't actually name the image file.  You'll have to make sure you do that after this is run using mysql_inser_id() to get that value.

Comment: This is not thread safe. You run the risk of collisions if multiple threads will be executing this simultaneously, which can easily happen in a web application. Also, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is per connection, so this would only work if all inserts happen on the same database connection and that connection is never closed. As soon as you re-open a new connection, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems redundant to store the id in a column when the ID is already in another column. Why not keep the id the same, and just worry about storing the file extension? (assuming `{id}.{jpg|gif}` is all that's going in the column, and was grossly mis-represented as a `text` type). Then query them and concat the id and the extension columns to get a result.

...or am I missing something